# How to change a JLabel text for x Seconds

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel

I want to change the `JLabel` text for a short moment (there's a counter and if someone types in the wrong answer in a text field, I want to show a "wrong answer" instead of the counter. After a few seconds I want to show the counter again.)

Comment: I have literaly no idea how to solve that problem. I tried timer but, which changes the text, but that doesnt reset back to the normal text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the *[fixed-delay execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57679756/11595728)* of some code you want to use a **timer object**, in this case [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). Here is a demo that applies to your situation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("One");
        JButton button = new JButton("Ok");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            String oldText = label.getText();
            label.setText("Changed");
            Timer timer = new Timer(2000, event -> {
                label.setText(oldText);
            });
            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();
        });
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

The listener for the button changes the text of the label and starts a Swing timer (here with a fuse of 2 seconds). Once the timer times out, it sends an action event to *its* (the timer's) registered listener, which in this case reverts the text to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable from outside your `paint()` void, to tell your `paint()` method to draw over or not draw the counter on the screen. For example,

```
boolean wrongAnswer = true;
public void paint(Graphics g){
    if(b){
        g.drawString("Wrong Answer.", x, y);
        //It's best to use a timer, see the link provided
    }
    else{
        g.drawString(counter+"", x, y)
    }
}
```

[why not to use thread.sleep for no reason, and explain it to a programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144846/why-not-to-use-thread-sleep-for-no-reason-and-explain-it-to-a-programmer)

Answer (score -1):

```
// change text to error
Thread.sleep(5000); // 5000ms = 5 seconds
// change text to counter
```

This a easy how you could do it. Obviously you should replace the comments with actual code.

Comment: Obviously he should add an if to his code for that. My code was just a solution for his timer problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144846/why-not-to-use-thread-sleep-for-no-reason-and-explain-it-to-a-programmer